# Show if the open interval and the zero set belong to the sigma algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $S$ denote the real line and that $C$ is set of all open sets in $S$. Let $F$ denote the smallest sigma algebra that contains $C$. Does the set {$0$} belong to $F$? Does the the interval $(a, b]$ belong to $F$? Could someone help to explain this further?

Comment: They all do - as Fred explains - actually it is quite hard to find sets that do not belong to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b \in \mathbb R$. Since $( - \infty,b) \cup(b, \infty)$ is open, we have $( - \infty,b) \cup(b, \infty) \in F$. Hence the complement of this set belongs to $F$. This means:

(*) $\{b\} \in F$ for all $b$.

$(a,b)$ is open, hence $(a,b)\in F$.

Can you now take from (*) that $(a,b ]\in F$ ?